# Can unary be used in Turing Machine?

Tags: turing-machines

Given a number in unary (0 = 1, 1 = 11, 2 = 111, 3 = 1111, ...), leave one blank symbol after it, and write the binary representation of the same number (0 = 0, 1 = 1, 2 = 10, 3 = 11, 4 = 100, ...). It is acceptable (not required) to write the number in a reverse order. When done, the TM should switch to the accepting state. No need to verify input, assume that input is 100% one unary number, and there is nothing else written on the tape.

Comment: Here's a hint: if you have a machine that can add 1 to an existing number written in binary, then you just have to add 1 to itself the appropriate number of times.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution based on Welbog's hint.

The TM will begin by writing a 0 one blank space after the end of the 1s. We know there will be at least a single 1 on the tape. Then, we can add one to our binary representation for each 1 we see to the left of the first blank. We may as well remember which unary 1s we've already processed by changing them to 0s. If we want to put the tape back like it was when we're done, we can write 1s back over the 0s to the left of the binary representation.

```
Q    T    Q'    T'    d
-----------------------
q0   1    q0    1     R    // scan right to first blank space
q0   #    q1    #     R    // after unary. then, write a 0
q1   #    q2    0     L    // to start the binary.

q2   #    q3    #     L    // scan left past any binary data
q2   0    q2    0     L    // to get to the blank separating
q2   1    q2    1     L    // unary and binary

q3   #    hA    #     R    // scan left for another unary
q3   0    q3    0     L    // digit, ignoring ones that have
q3   1    q4    0     R    // been processed. if done, halt.

q4   #    q5    #     R    // scan right to the blank separating
q4   0    q4    0     R    // unary and binary

q5   #    q2    1     L    // add one to the binary representation
q5   0    q2    1     L    // by toggling bits until you toggle a
q5   1    q5    0     R    // zero to a one, completing the addition
```

Example:

```
#111####  =>  #111####  =>  #111####  =>  #111####  => (next line)
 ^q0            ^q0            ^q0            ^q0

#111####  =>  #111#0##  =>  #111#0##  =>  #110#0##  => (next line)
     ^q1          ^q2          ^q3            ^q4

#110#0##  =>  #110#1##  =>  #110#1##  =>  #110#1##  => (next line)
     ^q5          ^q2          ^q3          ^q3

#100#1##  =>  #100#1##  =>  #100#1##  =>  #100#0##  => (next line)
   ^q4            ^q4            ^q5            ^q5

#100#01#  =>  #100#01#  =>  #100#01#  =>  #100#01#  => (next line)
     ^q2          ^q2          ^q3          ^q3

#100#01#  =>  #000#01#  =>  #000#01#  =>  #000#01#  => (next line)
 ^q3            ^q4            ^q4            ^q4

#000#01#  =>  #000#11#  =>  #000#11#  =>  #000#11#  => (next line)
     ^q5          ^q2          ^q3          ^q3

#000#11#  =>  #000#11#  =>  #000#11#
 ^q3          ^q3            ^hA
```